# Unable to type symbols like @ £ and so on

Tags: keyboard

I've tested various distros and I can't type symbols in any of them. I've tried different computers and keyboards and still no luck.

How do I fix?

Comment: How would you like to type them?

Answer (score 3):

Temporarily, you can use [CharacterMap](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CharacterMap)